# How can I include a Visual Studio project with the name 'User' into Azure DevOps Server?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfs

Is it possible to include a Visual Studio 2022 C# project with a name that includes `User` into Azure DevOps Server (TFS) source control?

My project naming convention is `[Org].[App].User`, and it's listed as `Invalid` in the Change Source Control status.  I'd rather keep the `User` in the name if possible, as it's the domain of my project.

[image: User project error]

I've tried searching the web and Stack Overflow for the answer but every time I search for `User` and `DevOps Server`/`TFS`, it brings up user configuration in the source control tool.

Comment: The name should not be an issue.

Comment: I assume this is a TFVC repo. Have you tried opening the 'Change Source Control' dialog and unbinding and then rebinding the projects?

Comment: @jessehouwing -- you're right, I renamed the project and it still wouldn't add to the solution.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I tried, and even after unbinding and rebinding, they're still showing as 'Invalid'.

Comment: I'm going to try to include a '.tfignore' file with the negate operator for those projects and see if that'll include them.

Comment: I'd guess the folder might not be part of the workspace definition or the `.sln` file contains a link to another source control system for that project, check it in a text editor to see what's in there.

Comment: Everything looks good in my `.sln` file.  I added the projects manually via Team Explorer and everything showed up as normal.  So strange they didn't get automatically added.  Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the projects manually via Team Explorer, and it added them to TFVC without issue.